# Is there any intuitive way to understand the relationship between the definitions of divergence and curl in terms of del and in terms of geometry?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Ok so.
There are, in essence, two ways to define the two derivatives of a vector field, curl and divergence.
The first way is to define a differentiation operator, del, or ∇:

∇ = (d/dx, d/dy, d/dz)

As ∇ is a pseudovector, there are two ways to multiply it by a vector field, V.

The first is the scalar, or dot product, which gives the divergence:

∇.V = div(V)

The second is the vector, or cross product, which gives the curl:

∇ x V = curl(V)

There is also a *different* way to define divergence and curl.

Divergence at a point is the ratio of the flux (surface integral of field out of a closed surface) over an infinitesimal surface enclosing an infinitesimal volume to that volume itself:

div = Φ/V

Curl is the infinitesimal circulation around a closed loop enclosing a point (I'm a bit fuzzier on the exact definition of curl).

If you extend these 'geometric' definitions of what the divergence and curl of a field V represent, you get two higher dimensional versions of the fundamental theorem of calculus, Stokes' theorem:

Surface integral of curl = line integral of field

And the divergence theorem:

Volume integral of divergence = surface integral of field

So my question is:

How can these two definitions be interpreted together?

What does Stokes' theorem/the divergence theorem suggest about the respective 'dimensions' of curl and divergence - clearly the disparity in the 3D/2D/1D integrals means **something** - and how does this relate to the del definition?

I'm not looking for a mathematical proof that these two definitions give equivalent answers, I know the proof. I'm asking for a intuitive reasoning as to why the 'scalar product derivative' of a vector field should have anything to do with volume and why the 'vector product derivative' should have anything to do with surface.

Comment: Don't leave Gauss' theorem out of the mix. All of them are special cases of what is usually called the generalized Stokes theorem that says for a form $\omega$ and a region $\Omega$ with boundary $\partial\Omega$, $$\int_{\Omega} d\omega = \oint_{\partial \Omega} \omega$$